# HMAC SHA256 sign on Java, Verify on C++ private-public keys

Tags: c++, openssl, sha256, sign

I try to sign some data by Java with private key and then verify it by C++ with public key. I user Java as client and C++ as server.
Java run on Windows, C++ on Ubuntu

in Java I use

```
key = "MIIEowIBAAKCAQ......s8mFoA2"; //private key
        
        
        byte[] b1 = Base64.decodeBase64(key);

this.Sign =  hmacSha256Base64("test", b1);

/**************/

public static String hmacSha256Base64(String message, byte[] secretKey) throws
      NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchProviderException {
       
       Mac hmacSha256;
       try {
        hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256", "BC");
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
        hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA-256");
       }
       SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "HmacSHA256");
       hmacSha256.init(secretKeySpec);
       // Build and return signature
       return Base64.encodeBase64String(hmacSha256.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8")));
      }
```

and on C++, to verify I real try different code, for example:

```
int verify_it(const unsigned char *msg, size_t mlen, const unsigned char *val, size_t vlen, EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    /* Returned to caller */
    int result = 0;
    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    unsigned char buff[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    size_t size;
    int rc;

    if (!msg || !mlen || !val || !vlen || !pkey)
        return 0;

    ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_new();
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("EVP_MD_CTX_create failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestSignInit(ctx, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, pkey);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignInit failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    rc = EVP_DigestSignUpdate(ctx, msg, mlen);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignUpdate failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    size = sizeof(buff);
    rc = EVP_DigestSignFinal(ctx, buff, &size);
    if (rc != 1) {
        printf("EVP_DigestSignFinal failed, error 0x%lx\n", ERR_get_error());
        goto err;
    }

    result = (vlen == size) && (CRYPTO_memcmp(val, buff, size) == 0);
err:
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(ctx);
    return result;
} 

RSA* createPublicRSA(std::string TermId, bool is_local) {
    RSA *rsa = NULL;
    BIO *keybio;

    FILE * fp = fopen((SettingsConfig["UserKeys"] + "user_public/" + TermId).c_str(), "rb");

    if (fp != 0)
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    
    return rsa;
}

size_t calcDecodeLength(const char* b64input) {
    size_t len = strlen(b64input), padding = 0;

    if (b64input[len - 1] == '=' && b64input[len - 2] == '=') //last two chars are =
        padding = 2;
    else if (b64input[len - 1] == '=') //last char is =
        padding = 1;
    return (len * 3) / 4 - padding;
}

void Base64Decode(const char* b64message, unsigned char** buffer, size_t* length) {
    BIO *bio, *b64;

    int decodeLen = calcDecodeLength(b64message);
    *buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(decodeLen + 1);
    (*buffer)[decodeLen] = '\0';

    bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(b64message, -1);
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

    *length = BIO_read(bio, *buffer, strlen(b64message));
    BIO_free_all(bio);
}       
std::string test = "XChhsTE....NkE="; //Sign from Java      
    std::string msg = "test";
    
    RSA* publicRSA = createPublicRSA("#1.pem", false); //public key

    EVP_PKEY* pubKey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pubKey, publicRSA);


    unsigned char* encMessage;
    size_t encMessageLength;

    Base64Decode(test.c_str(), &encMessage, &encMessageLength);

    int result_sign = verify_it((unsigned char*)msg.c_str(), msg.length(), encMessage, encMessageLength, pubKey);

    std::cout << std::to_string(result_sign) << std::endl; //return 0
```

And any others examples return false.  I don't know what is problem, please help! Thanks!

p.s. private key:

> 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

public key:

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAra2jau89VIfcunyOth5O
> 08EZqFVSgVzk9Tv0ELG+zH89D/s0DMLSkACXUSYq2EFRXUS05doajB55ZVoD2qYi
> UjJPrZDnPS+H3f/9tqRf+o2bbb4DWRd9MJbMt2E2Q8auIN3M49XvlQnZ2+dSvplL
> epYv6H+fbILBsYfQUxh4RX5B+qvk1JdbMh1rhgLV6y9/lYkF3UlL8W5EBA2A1YQv
> grwl/nBjXTTk3PVv+OmWGFRFE0BGuf7oYEuoX86732gAtLkImqLNeNNhgUVVhFiD
> UOOyWjybxH9UiH28eYBZqzJlyY9D3xeC3ZUkTvfJOURK5t8vagS/t8Vu3xsMHWQ7
> DwIDAQAB
> -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

message: 12105333071

signaturee from Java: XChhsTE+Yr4wkiibvTFiLTMhJ8tLqYo7WQs///VtNkE=

Comment: Do you have a test key and message we can use?

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes, I edit message and add it

Comment: Hmac sha256 isn't realy a Private/Public key encryption so you  don't need a KEYPAIR.

Comment: I try use SHA256withRSA in java and evp_sha256 in C++ (openssl) but verify is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Just using HMACSHA256 is not the same as Private/Public Key signature. The full name of HMACSHA256 is "Hash-based Message Authentication Code" and you "sign" and "verify" this with the same "key" that is just a byte array and has nothing to do with Private or Public Key.

Of course you can take the encoded bytes of the Private/Public key as input, but when doing so (I do **NOT** recommend this)
you need to pass the **same** key to the verification part.

I setup two small programs to show how it works. For Java I'm using your code except of using Bouncy Castle as "native" Java
should have this build in. As well I left out the apache-Base64-conversion as it's build in as well. The C#-part is the same program but has a "verification" output.

**Both code samples do not have any exceptional handling and are for educational purposes only.**

Result of Java-code:

```
HMAC SHA256 sign on Java, Verify on C++ private-public keys
hmacSha256 (Base64): /1qkanJi8onWOxVe02MO/Wf1922aKzSTSfJk6E7o1x0=
```

Result of C#-code:

```
HMAC SHA256 sign on Java, Verify on C++ private-public keys
HMACSHA256 in C#: /1qkanJi8onWOxVe02MO/Wf1922aKzSTSfJk6E7o1x0=
HMACSHA256 Java : /1qkanJi8onWOxVe02MO/Wf1922aKzSTSfJk6E7o1x0=
Hashes are equal: True
```

Java-code:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Org {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        System.out.println("HMAC SHA256 sign on Java, Verify on C++ private-public keys");
        String message = "12105333071";
        String key = "12345678901234567";
        String result = hmacSha256Base64(message, key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        System.out.println("hmacSha256 (Base64): " + result);
    }
    public static String hmacSha256Base64(String message, byte[] secretKey) throws
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        Mac hmacSha256;
        try {
            hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            hmacSha256 = Mac.getInstance("HMAC-SHA-256");
        }
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "HmacSHA256");
        hmacSha256.init(secretKeySpec);
        // Build and return signature
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hmacSha256.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

C#-code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HMAC SHA256 sign on Java, Verify on C++ private-public keys");
            string message = "12105333071";
            string key = "12345678901234567";
            string expectedHashBase64 = "/1qkanJi8onWOxVe02MO/Wf1922aKzSTSfJk6E7o1x0="; // from Java
            // generate HMACSHA256
            string hmacSha256DigestBase64 = HmacSha256DigestBase64(key, message);
            Console.WriteLine("HMACSHA256 in C#: " + hmacSha256DigestBase64);
            Console.WriteLine("HMACSHA256 Java : " + expectedHashBase64);
            Console.WriteLine("Hashes are equal: " + hmacSha256DigestBase64.Equals(expectedHashBase64, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    
        private static string HmacSha256DigestBase64(string secret, string message)
        {
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 cryptographer = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(keyBytes);
            byte[] bytes = cryptographer.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Golang code to complete the collection (tested to produce the exactly same result as the java code form Michael Fehr:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    b64 "encoding/base64"
)

func main() {

    secret := "12345678901234567"
    data := "12105333071"
    fmt.Printf("Secret: %s Data: %s\n", secret, data)

    // Create a new HMAC by defining the hash type and the key (as byte array)
    h := hmac.New(sha256.New, []byte(secret))

    // Write Data to it
    h.Write([]byte(data))

    // Get result and base64 encode the string
    sha := b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))

    fmt.Println("Result: " + sha)

}
```